# continuity of coefficients imply uniqueness in law of the solutions of an sde?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

let's consider a simple sde of the form
$$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
for $t\leq T$ and $b$,$\sigma$ continuous in $(t,x)$, $t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is: does uniqueness in law hold?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, no. The generic counterexample is
\begin{equation}
dX_{t}=|X_{t}|^{\alpha}dB_{t},\quad X_{0}=0
\end{equation}
with $\alpha\in(0,1/2)$. Then, $0$ gives one solution and another can be constructed by time-change. Take a look e.g. into the book 'Singular Stochastic Differential Equations' of Cherny et.al.

Comment: perfect, many thanks!

Comment: if you're happy with the answer I wouldn't mind if you 'accept' it ;)